# Send mail via rake task : Missing host to link to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, heroku, rake

I know this has been seen many times, but I don't get what I do wrong. I'm trying to send mails via a rake task, and I got this error

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

in the `staging` environment (hosted on heroku). What's bothering me is that when I fire up a console, I can send mails without any troubles. In development, no troubles wether I'm seding the mail directly of via the rake task.

You can see the environment files, the mailer class and the rake task in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3376803). I really don't get what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

When I get this, I have to put the :host value in the App::Application.configure block in production.rb.

I don't know if this translates to heroku though.

In production.rb, add the following inside the configure block:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
    :host => "your-domain.com" 
  }
```

If this needs to be variable (for heroku), you could probably use an environment variable here.

Comment: This is what I did for the `staging` environment

Comment: Is it possible that you're not running the rake task in your staging environment?

Comment: both `RACK_ENV` & `RAILS_ENV` are set to `staging`, according to `heroku config`. I ran the rake task myself with `heroku run RAILS_ENV=staging rake mailers:congrats --trace`, but was not luckier.

Comment: Can you run it locally in staging? It's possible that heroku are changing or deleting your config file.

Comment: I can send my mail with `Routines.congrats(book).deliver` from the heroku console without any troubles in staging, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I specify the host in each method that uses `url_for`. Luckily for me it's only two calls, but I'd like to know the answer if somebody knows better.